# how to display interstitial ads on 'X' number of clicks in webview android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, webview, admob

I have used the interstitial ads in my android app at the time interval of 1.5minutes but I want to show the ads on the number of clicks in the app itself. below is the code that i have used to show ads. Inside `onCreate` of main activity i have used this code:

```
public void run() {
        Log.i("hello", "world");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", " Interstitial not loaded");
                }

                prepareAd();


            }
        });

    }
}, 90, 90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

outside main I have used this :

```
public void prepareAd(){

mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-480455567412xxx/855xxxxxx");
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

}
what changes should i made to display ads on number of clicks in android?
lets say 4 or 5 maybe?

also, tell me how can I detect clicks in `Webview` because my app is opening a Webview and I haven't placed any button in the app so that I can check by using `onClick` method.So please tell me how to detect clicks in `Webview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count all the clicks and set the ads to load when you reach the amount of clicks needed to trigger the ads.

In the beginning...

```
// Set how many clicks needed to trigger ads
int triggerClicks = 5;
int countClicks = 0;
```

Something like this for counting and triggering the ads.

```
public void clickCount() {

    // Count
    countClicks++;

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() && countClicks >= triggerClicks) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        // Reset clicks again
        countClicks = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: how can I check whether the user has clicked in the app?? @John T

Comment: That's a broad question. It depends on how your app works and what it does. You have to do it at the same time as the user perform an action. For example, click a button. You use an onClickListener for that.

Comment: actually, my app is opening a webview and there is no button that I have placed in the webview only website is getting opened and the user clicks on the website through my app. So, in that case, how can I detect? @John T

Comment: You would use an onTouchListener on the webview and then within the onTouch method you would count the clicks. A good article about this can be found here: https://medium.com/@kpbird/android-webview-detect-html-element-on-click-263431c52e01

Comment: I used the code of this link https://medium.com/@kpbird/android-webview-detect-html-element-on-click-263431c52e01 but it could able to detect first click only after that it wasn't detecting clicks

Comment: Check this, scroll down to handling multiple touches: https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Touch_and_Multi-touch_Event_Handling_in_Android_Studio